# Autocomplete num jTextfield - adaptar classe

Tags: java, jtextfield

Consegui encontrar [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186955/create-a-autocompleting-textbox-in-java-with-a-dropdown-list) um código para fazer autocomplete num jTextfield. Como sou novo a programar, já tentei adaptar esse código para utilizar em JTextfields de outras classes que tenho mas ainda não consegui.

Tentei colocar esta parte do código na ação do meu jTextfield mas diz que a classe AutoSuggestor não é publica e por isso não a posso utilizar no meu package:

```
  private void fActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
_global.AutoSuggestor autoSuggestor = new _global.AutoSuggestor(f, frame, null, Color.WHITE.brighter(), Color.BLUE, Color.RED, 0.75f) {
        @Override
        boolean wordTyped(String typedWord) {

            //create list for dictionary this in your case might be done via calling a method which queries db and returns results as arraylist
            ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
            words.add("hello");
            words.add("heritage");
            words.add("happiness");
            words.add("goodbye");
            words.add("cruel");
            words.add("car");
            words.add("war");
            words.add("will");
            words.add("world");
            words.add("wall");


            setDictionary(words);
            //addToDictionary("bye");//adds a single word

            return super.wordTyped(typedWord);//now call super to check for any matches against newest dictionary
        }
    };        

}
```

Já a tentei colocar pública na classe Test que é a que funciona o autocomplete mas sem sucesso. Alguma dica por onde começar a ajustar esse autocomplete a textFields meus?

Talvez passar pelo construtor o textField e a Lista de palavras? Mas como depois adaptar no meu código?

Comment: Já consegui adaptar o código como queria agora gostava de saber onde é que mexo no posicionamento da lista de sugestões, porque me está a aparecer muito em cima do textField.

Comment: Se percebi o que disseste acho que deve de alterar esta linha de codigo `autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(textField.getWidth(), 30));` class: `AutoSuggestor` função: `showPopUpWindow`

Comment: Sim sim era essa linha de código. Obrigado !

Comment: @jsantos1991 poderia postar como resposta para resolver o tópico, não?

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo a tua pergunta:

> gostava de saber onde é que mexo no posicionamento da lista de
>   sugestões, porque me está a aparecer muito em cima do textField.

Podes fazer essa alteração na classe:

```
AutoSuggestor
```

No método:

```
showPopUpWindow
```

Nesta linha de código:

```
autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(textField.getWidth(), 30));
```